# How to add new element in a specific position (in pixels) without complying with TableLayoutPanel rules?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, tablelayoutpanel

I have set a TableLayoutPanel as a layout to organise my inputs. That was a good idea up to the moment when I realised that I had to add new elements that are not supposed to be in a specific cell in the table (They must span across table cells, but cells have to remain untouched)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the **starting** cell for the control

```
Panel pan = new Panel() {BackColor = Color.Red, Parent = tableLayoutPanel1 };
```

either like this:

```
tableLayoutPanel1.SetCellPosition(pan, new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(1, 2));
```

or like this:

```
tableLayoutPanel1.SetColumn(pan, 1);
tableLayoutPanel1.SetRow(pan, 2);
```

Then you can set the **spans** from that position like this:

```
tableLayoutPanel1.SetColumnSpan(pan, 3);
tableLayoutPanel1.SetRowSpan(pan, 2);
```

And finally you can **fine-tune the position at pixel-level** by setting the control's `Margin`:

```
  pan.Margin = new Padding(55, 5, 0, 0);
```

[image]

Note however that a spanned range acts like a cell: It can only contain one control, so you **cannot** place any **other** `Control` in the **spanned** range! If you **need more** controls in the **same range** you need to **nest** them all in a `Panel` or other `Container`!