# Controlling the exact position of a control on a WinForms TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I need the grid-like structure at the back of my main form, so using the TableLayoutPanel. Now, I need to place controls at "exact locations" on this panel. How can I achieve that ? I know how to put a control inside a cell, specifying the row & column#, but is there a way of managing rowspan, columnspan, and margins like in WPF grid ?

One more thing. I am hosting the TableLayoutPanel inside another Panel, and that 2nd Panel is basically inside a WindowsFormsHost in a WPF project.

This is how my TableLayoutPanel looks right now:

[image]

Comment: Have a look [at this post!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39139047/how-to-add-new-element-in-a-specific-position-in-pixels-without-complying-with/39143074?s=2|0.0000#39143074)

Comment: It is the job of TLP to give the control its position, not yours.  You can move it around a bit by setting the control's Margin property.  But high odds that you should not be using TLP, it is not a "grid" control.  Purely meant for layout, nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `Panel` to `Cell` then add `Button` to `Panel` controls and set `top` and `left` for `Button`.

```
Panel panel = new Panel();
Button button = new Button();

panel.Controls.Add(button);
panel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
button.Top = 5;
button.Left = 5;

tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(panel, 0,0);
tableLayoutPanel.SetColumnSpan(panel,2);
tableLayoutPanel.SetRowSpan(panel,2);
```

Comment: Good one, Hossein. Thanks. :)